# How to detect the user OS/browser info in web(using php, js, html)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, windows, apache

We make two version setup packages, win-32.msi and win-64.msi, and put them to our website for user to download.

But I just want to using one web link. When user using windows-32bit OS to click the link, he would get the win-32.msi, using windows-64-bit OS would get win-64.msi.

We use php, js, html in our web code, setting in apache.

There was a method we used before: browsercap.ini. But we found IE10 browser in win8-64bit give us win8-32bit information which was wrong.

So are there any other solutions?

Comment: please check link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641454/php-browser-and-os-detection-showing-chrome-instead-of-opera

may be this will help you

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to know the OS bit version, 32 or 64. browsercap.ini has the full information. It worked well at almost time, but win8-64 IE10 would be wrong..

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can use the [navigator](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp) object to get some info about the local system:

```
console.log(navigator.appVersion);
```

On my system this yields:

> 5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36

You can then parse this to work out where to send the user.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can do this in `Apache` as well by using `mod_rewrite` and looking at the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` variable. More information about this can be found in the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) documentation.

Something like this could work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (WOW64|OtherMatch)
RewriteRule ^(/path/to/dl-packages)/win-32.msi $1/win-64.msi [R,L]
```

This is more to show the basic consept and you might want to fine tune the `(WOW64|OtherMatch)` string that should match the 64bit clients, not sure if `WOW64` will match all Windows 64 bit browsers. Also I am matching the `URL` to the `win-32.msi` package in my `RewriteRule` that would be the default package, and if a 64bit client try to get it it will be redirected to the 64 bit version instead. Depending on your site, you might want to handle this differently.